# SyntaxError for code : invalide syntax on 'def function' Grade letter

Tags: python, spyder

calculate and return the letter grade that would appear in the transcript

i have tried my code, in the past and it seemed to have worked without a problem, but now, i am getting a invalid syntax, and im not sure of the reason.

```
#python

def letter_grade(pct):

    if pct <= 49:
        return 'F'
    elif pct <= 52:
        return 'D-'
    elif pct <= 56:
        return 'D'
    elif pct <= 59:
        return 'D+'
    elif pct <= 62:
        return 'C-'
    elif pct <= 66:
        return 'C'
    elif pct <= 69:
        return 'C+'
    elif pct <= 72:
        return 'B-'
    elif pct <= 76:
        return 'B'
    elif pct <= 79:
        return 'B+'
    elif pct <= 84:
        return 'A-'
    elif pct <= 89:
        return 'A'
    else: 
        return 'A+'

# input letter_grade(45)

expeted => # input letter_grade(45) --> F

actual result => # def letter_grade(45)

  File "<ipython-input-11-06219c433935>", line 1

    def letter_grade(45)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Just use `letter_grade(45)` to call the function

Answer (score 2):

It's a little difficult to read because your formatting is off, but I think you're trying to **call** the function with `def` in front. The `def` only goes in front of the function definition, not when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the return type. You need to store the value in a variable in order to get the result. 
Try calling the function by using

`value = letter_grade(45)
print(value)`